# Run command after docker container is started

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I've prepared a docker-compose file to deploy container with database:

```
services:
  tmp-db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: yourStrong(!)Password
    ports:
    - 1433:1433
```

It is okay. But now I need to create a database and build its structure. I need to execute some sql commands.
To check if i am able to do this I added `command` to the service:

```
services:
  tmp-db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: yourStrong(!)Password
    command: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P yourStrong(!)Password -Q "SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases"
    ports:
    - 1433:1433
```

However I got the following errors:

```
tmp-db_1  | Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
tmp-db_1  | Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
tmp-db_1  | Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

I feel the command is executed before Sql Server instance is started. How can I fix it? How can I execute some sql after Sql Server is started?

Comment: check this doc https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: From the Docker Hub page for this image, MS suggests [this project](https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app) as an example of setting up schema and data on startup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that only one command is executed in a container. When you specify the command in `docker-compose.yml` it overrides the default command, which was supposed to start the container. So you have two options

**Run the command manually**

```
services:
  tmp-db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: yourStrong(!)Password
    ports:
    - 1433:1433
```

Then you can execute

```
docker-compose exec tmp-db /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P yourStrong(!)Password -Q "SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases"
```

**Have two services - one for server & one for data loading**

```
services:
  load-db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
    command: sh -c 'sleep 10 && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P yourStrong(!)Password -Q "SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases"'
    network_mode: service:tmp-db
  tmp-db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: yourStrong(!)Password
    ports:
    - 1433:1433
```

In this approach we launch another container with the command to load our data, we run it on the network of our DB server container. This is done just to avoid the host name of the DB, if you prefer you can pass the host name also as `tmp-db` and remove the `network_mode: service:tmp-db`.

Comment: The two services approach for data loading is a new one to me, neat idea +1

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani, thank you, good approach. However if I run the same file I get `Unsupported config option for services.load-db: 'network'`. And if I add `-H tmp-db` I get the issue as described in question. How can I set the host correctly?

Comment: My bad it should be `network_mode` instead of `network`

Comment: If you want to set the host directly without `network_mode` you should use `-S tmp-db` instead of `-H`

Comment: How does it infer the order? Can you explain what happens exactly? So it brings up the actual DB first, then it run the command on that container? Why need to specify `image` in `load-db` if we're running the command on the other container?

Comment: `load-db` this connects to the `tmp-db` which is the actual SQL server. The command runs in `load-db` not in `tmp-db` that is why you use the same image so that it has SQLCmd command present