# Launching docker command from docker-compose v.3 file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm learning about Docker and I'm at first steps.

I've to 'refresh' postgres image from compose file to initialize db scripts as YOSIFKIT here do through shell (https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/193).

here is my Docker file:

```
FROM postgres:9.6.7

COPY docker-postgresql-9.6.7/prova.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

and here is my compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgresql_rdbms:
    restart: always
    image: postgres-prova
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker-postgresql-9.6.7/Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "docker run -it --rm postgres-prova ls -ln /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d && docker run -it --rm postgres-prova && postgres"
    environment:
      PG_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
```

HOW can I insert a command in a compose-file to do "docker run -it --rm imageToReload" ???
Because I've seen that "command:" in compose file works inside the container, but I want operate ON the container, on a upper level (=manage the container from the compose file, after the container creation)

Thank you very much

Comment: See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48342406/run-command-after-docker-container-is-started/48343276#48343276

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want docker-compose to delete/remove the container after every run so that the build is run each time and a fresh prova.sql file can be copied into the image each time the service is brought up. The `--force-recreate` [flag](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) is probably what you need.

The command directive within the yaml file provides the command that is run inside the container.

Comment: Thanks sxm1972!! this works, but If I have a compose file with multiple services, of which  'postgresql_rdbms' is one of them, and want to force recreate ONLY that, how can I launche the compose up? (example: docker compose up -d  postgresql_rdbms --force-recreate ?) I want compose up ALL but forcerecreate only THAT service! thank you so much!